# ORA-01552: cannot use system rollback segment for non-system tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I tried to insert records into a newly created table using SQL*Loader and received the error,

> ORA-01552: cannot use system rollback segment for non-system tablespace

I googled the error and every webpage said the same thing: set `undo_management` to `AUTO`.  I did that then shutdown and restarted the database.  Afterwards the login for my regular user failed. I returned `undo_management` to `MANUAL` and I can login but not insert the data.

I even tried manually inserting from SQL> command line but get the same error message.

```
INSERT INTO H2O_FEET
    (DATEFROM, WATERLEVEL, SIGMA, LOCATION, DATETO)
VALUES
    (TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-08-18 00:00:00:000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH.MI.SS.FFF'), 8.12, 0.039, 'Coyote Creek', (cast (NULL as timestamp)))
```

My regular user is the table owner and has INSERT privileges.

I'm on a small project, currently without an Oracle DBA, and my own skills involve writing and executing simple queries against pre-loaded data (don't worry, its a test box not production).

I'm Using:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.1.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-81-generic x86_64)

Comment: I solved my problem by changing both the undo_management parameter and the undo_tablespace. As sysdba  I created a second, non-system, undo tablespace. I changed the undo_management parameter to AUTO, shutdown and restarted the database, changed the undo tablespace. I exited oracle and successfully logged in as my regular user.  That account was able to load the data to the table.